# Ввести строку на русском языке

Tags: c++

Есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

        cout << "Введите строку" << endl;
        string s1;
        getline(cin, s1);
        cout << s1 << endl;

        system("pause");
    }
}
```

`getline()` нужен, чтобы ввести одну большую  строчку с пробелами.

Консоль пишет:

```
Введите строку(вывод)
Привет(ввод)
?п4кцр(просто не понятные символы(в итоге вывод ввода).
```

Что не так? Ведь `setlocale` я использовал. Однако, если удалить `setlocale`, то вывод ввода будет корректный на русском, но вот первый вывод `Введите строку` станет нечитабельным бредом. Как это решить?

Comment: Ну во-первых я ни разу не видел использование setlocale в цикле. Его обычно используют в начале программы один раз. Может не в этом дело, но это просто первая догадка, пришедшая в голову

Comment: Я просто пример что в голову пришло,то и написал ,чтобы каждый раз не запускать прогу по новому использовал бесконечный цикл для примера . Дело в том ,что ввести (cin) русские буквы в строку можно , а при выводе получаются непонятные символы ,хотя setlocale() имеется .

Comment: __setmode для всех потоков выставлять вроде надо.